# Determine If Polygon exists/intersects inside a BBOX

Tags: mapbox, extents

I have a polygon like so,(Lng, Lat)

```
[
 [-125.26367187500567, 56.580978332369256]
 [-125.39550781250242, 55.92182528855989]
 [-123.98925781250418, 56.2406121548556]
 [-124.51660156250529, 56.265025063810896]
 [-125.26367187500567, 56.580978332369256]
]
```

I want to determine if this polygon intersects a BBOX.
EG. Given below.

```
[
    [
        -124.956405,
        48.393832
    ],
    [
        -124.956405,
        49.031749
    ],
    [
        -123.895123,
        49.031749
    ],
    [
        -123.895123,
        48.393832
    ],
    [
        -124.956405,
        48.393832
    ]
]
```

How would I do so?
Without turf or any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of the context of your question, a bit more detail would be helpful.  This is my best guess at what you would be looking for based on your question.

I am assuming your polygon is in a layer, let's give it a layer id of 'polygon-layer' while your bbox is stored in a variable as geojson.

I would use queryRenderedFeatures to determine if they overlap.  If the polygon-layer has multiple features just use a unique property to identify it from the array after the queryRenderedFeatures

```
var bbox = ~ geojson object ~;
var polygon_name = 'specific_name';

var intersecting_features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, { layers: ['polygon-layer'] });

if (intersecting_features.length > 0) {

     for (var i = 0; i < intersecting_features.length; i++) {
          var name = intersecting_features[i].properties.name;
          if (name === polygon_name) {
               console.log('intersection');
               var selected_polygon = intersecting_features[i];
          };
     };
} else {
     console.log('no intersection');
};
```